# window.addEventListener causes browser slowdowns - Firefox only. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, addeventlistener

Im writing about the functions requested by my client to check of user session. 
The goal is to ask for the password after 5 minutes of user inactivity.
I ran into a rather strange problem in Firefox.

PREMISE: To work usually I use Chrome. In fact, when writing the functions I did not notice any problems.

Analyzing the result of the functions in Firefox I realized that something is wrong. In particular, the browser behaves strangely. Every time the EventListener event is executed, the browser redraws the page by moving the objects and in addition it seems very slow in executing the events, which doesn't happen in Chrome. Why??? ...i dont know!

Here is the code:

```
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 300; //seconds
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
var InfoSess = document.getElementById('infosession');
var SessinStandBy = 0;

function force_reflow(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    SessinStandBy == 0 ? InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>active</strong> [event: click]' : InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>stand-by, please insert password!</strong>';
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
});
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    SessinStandBy == 0 ? InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>active</strong> [event: mouse moved]' : InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>stand-by, please insert password!</strong>';
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
});
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    SessinStandBy == 0 ? InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>active</strong> [event: keyboard pressed]' : InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>stand-by, please insert password!</strong>';
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
});
var myInterval = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime,1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {

    var _DiffTime = IDLE_TIMEOUT-_idleSecondsCounter;

    var _MinutDiffTime = Math.floor(_DiffTime / 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_DiffTime / 60) : Math.floor(_DiffTime / 60);
    var _SecondsDiffTime = Math.floor(_DiffTime % 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_DiffTime % 60) : Math.floor(_DiffTime % 60);
    var _Countdown = _MinutDiffTime+'m:'+_SecondsDiffTime+'s';

    var _MinutCounter = Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter / 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter / 60) : Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter / 60);
    var _SecondsCounter = Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter % 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter % 60) : Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter % 60);
    var _IncativeTime = _MinutCounter+'m:'+_SecondsCounter+'s';

    _idleSecondsCounter++; // add 1s
    if (_idleSecondsCounter > 30) {
        InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Sessione intattiva da <strong>'+_IncativeTime+'</strong> | in pausa tra: <strong>'+_Countdown+'</strong>';
        force_reflow();
    }

    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        window.clearInterval(myInterval);
        SessinStandBy = 1;
        InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>stand-by, please insert password!</strong>'; 
        force_reflow();
    }
}
```

I added a force reflow function, I solved the problem of moving objects on the page but not of slowness.

I hope for help from the stackoverflow community. Thank you!

UPDATE CODE

```
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 300; //seconds
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
var InfoSess = document.getElementById('infosession');
var SessinStandBy = 0;

function force_reflow(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
}

function display_session_message(_event_type) {
    if (prec_event_execute != _event_type) {
        prec_event_execute = _event_type;
        InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session <strong>active</strong> - User event: ' + _event_type;
        force_reflow();
        //console.log('ui refresh');
    } else {
        //console.log('silent check');
    }
}

var update_layout = _.debounce(function (e) {
    display_session_message(e.type);
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
},1000);

window.addEventListener('click', update_layout, false, { passive: true });
window.addEventListener('keypress', update_layout, false, { passive: true });
window.addEventListener('mousemove', update_layout, false, { passive: true });

var myInterval = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime,1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
    var _DiffTime = IDLE_TIMEOUT-_idleSecondsCounter;
    var _MinutDiffTime = Math.floor(_DiffTime / 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_DiffTime / 60) : Math.floor(_DiffTime / 60);
    var _SecondsDiffTime = Math.floor(_DiffTime % 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_DiffTime % 60) : Math.floor(_DiffTime % 60);
    var _Countdown = _MinutDiffTime+'m:'+_SecondsDiffTime+'s';
    var _MinutCounter = Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter / 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter / 60) : Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter / 60);
    var _SecondsCounter = Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter % 60) < 10 ? '0'+Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter % 60) : Math.floor(_idleSecondsCounter % 60);
    var _IncativeTime = _MinutCounter+'m:'+_SecondsCounter+'s';
    _idleSecondsCounter++; // add 1s
    if (_idleSecondsCounter > 30) {
        InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Sessione intattiva da <strong>'+_IncativeTime+'</strong> | in pausa tra: <strong>'+_Countdown+'</strong>';
        force_reflow();
    }
    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        window.clearInterval(myInterval);
        SessinStandBy = 1;
        InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>stand-by, please insert password!</strong>'; 
        force_reflow();
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that commenting on the update line of the message, the problem does not occur. `SessinStandBy == 0 ? InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>active</strong> [event: scroll]' : InfoSess.innerHTML = 'Session: <strong>stand-by, please insert password!</strong>';` Therefore I can say with certainty that the problem is caused by the modification of the label. Unfortunately I cannot comment on why I have to specify to the user what he is doing.

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but the logic seems way more complex than it needs to be. If you're using jQuery, why use *addEventListener*?

Comment: Quite right. Unfortunately, the result is the same even when doing:`$(window).on("click",function() {};`

Comment: The scroll event handler is notorious for slowing pages down as it fires so regularly. Although your code in that handler is relatively simple I'd suggest, as a first test, to comment that handler out and see if the performance issues remain.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a session monitor written in JS is largely useless (from a security point of view). This would be trivial to work around.

Comment: Sorry. The event was click. Scroll is the result of a test.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is only the function to manage the UI. Of course I also wrote the server part to pause the session, otherwise with F5 the system does not work! ;)

Comment: If you update the innerHTML of something on almost every little event that might happen on the page, then I wouldn’t wonder that frequent repaints might slow stuff down. I think you should at least _debounce_ your event handling here.

Comment: @CBroe Tnk for your comment. The underscore.js is very useful for my problem. I immediately understood its usefulness and power. I think he must study it lunge before using it in production. Thank you.